# How to parse filters in inclusion_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

In my customized inclusion tag, like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('templatetags/div_text.html')
def div_text(text):
    return  {'text' : text}
```

while in another page, like show.html, when i am trying to use this tag like

```
{% div_text list|length %}
```

django raises an error:

```
Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [list|length]
```

I am wondering why it would happen.

Comment: looks like you are trying to use the length filter inside a tag, I dont think that it is possible. And why write such a tag? Just pass your text into the context as variable on which you could apply the length filter.

Comment: as a matter of fact, i find that built-in tags could parse those built-in filters. An example would be {% if list|length > %}, it indeed works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django from version 1.3 has "with" tag.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with

Try this code

```
{% with list_length=list|length %}
    {% div_text list_length %}
{% endwith %}
```